# How to check in which category each employee has sold the most goods? I can display only employee's name and sold goods

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, mssql-jdbc

The whole table

```
USE Northwind
SELECT MAX(TotalOrder)


FROM vwEmployesAndMostSoldCategories
GROUP MAX(TotalOrder)
```

What I am only able to output

```
USE Northwind
SELECT
   FullName
   , MAX(TotalOrder) AS TheMaxSoldUnits
FROM vwEmployesAndMostSoldCategories
GROUP BY FullName
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `TOP` query here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT FullName, CatgegoryName,
           SUM(TotalOrder) AS SumTotalOrder,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FullName
                              ORDER BY SUM(TotalOrder) DESC) rn
    FROM vwEmployesAndMostSoldCategories
    GROUP BY FullName, CategoryName
)

SELECT FullName, CategoryName, SumTotalOrder AS TotalOrder
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

If a given employee might be *tied* for having two or more categories with the same order total, and you want to show all ties, then replace `ROW_NUMBER`, with `RANK`.

Comment: Sorry, I asked the wrong question. I need to find out in which category each employee has sold the most goods. Don't know why I cannot output 3 columns with an employee+Category+TotalUnits,

Comment: @AlexeyOrel ... lesson learned, please always show starting and ending data in your SQL question.  In any case, I have updated with what I interpret your question to actually be asking.

Comment: Dude! You have helped me a lot! That was my first comment on this legendary website =) Wish you all the best!

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you correctly, you can do this using `with ties`:

```
select top (1) with ties e.*
from vwEmployesAndMostSoldCategories e
order by rank() over(partition by fullname order by totalorders desc)
```

For each employee, this returns the row with the greatest `totalorders` (if there are top ties, all tied rows of the same employee are returned). It doesn't look like you need aggregation here.

Comment: @ GMB Could you tell me what does "e" mean in this case? I tried your suggestion but for me, it doesn't work

Comment: @AlexeyOrel: `e` is an alias for `vwEmployesAndMostSoldCategories` in the query. What is wrong in the results you are getting th this query?

Comment: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'vwEmployesAndMostSoldCategories'.
Don't know how to run this query, looks like something is missing.
Do you have an idea of how to write this query without an alias? I've been started studying SQL for a month, so this alias is confusing me.

Comment: @AlexeyOrel: just run the query as it is. It will not raise that error.

Comment: I have tried already but I got an error and Don't know why:

Invalid object name 'vwEmployesAndMostSoldCategories'